# Connecting to the Marketing cloud SOAP API - different schema

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

We're using integration system to connect to the Marketing cloud SAOP API. We put the relevant URL and we got a specific schema. 
BUT,
In all the documentations and examples we saw - the XML we should sent doesn't match the schema. 
For example, we tried to sent CreateRequest where there is a node named "EmailAddress" under "Objects" node. 
In the schema generated by putting the URL we can't see this structure.

Can you please advise? What are we missing?
Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

What ObjectType are you trying to create? Are you using C# , Java, PHP? or sending raw SOAP request to endpoint

CreateRequest uses APIObject which can be any type, e.g. Email, List, Data Extension, QueryDefinition etc. "EmailAddress" might be an attribute of that object, you need to check that specific ObjectType see what attribute you need to send, for example, below XML is for creating Email object.

```
<soap:Body>
  <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Options/>
     <Objects xsi:type="Email">
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Name>Test Email with Content Areas</Name>
        <Description>Description</Description>
        <HTMLBody>Example HTML Body</HTMLBody>
        <Subject>Test Subject</Subject>
        <EmailType>HTML</EmailType>
        <IsHTMLPaste>true</IsHTMLPaste>
     </Objects>
  </CreateRequest>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
We're trying to send raw SOAP request to an endpoint. our confuse is due to the fact that the schema of the "CreateRequest" doesn't match to any other schema of the examples. As you said, there are different properties for different objects types. BUT, in our integration system creating a specific schema without the ability to use the schema given from the WSDL, is problematic. 
Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @DanaFurman Does your system have the flexibility for you to manually construct the SOAP message without using generated schema? If you can let me know what ObjectType you are trying to create, I can give you code example in details